# Run same tests with many different configuration

Tags: c#, nunit

Is there an easy way to have a lot of unit tests to run several times with a different setup using NUnit. Say :

- I have many tests
- Each test should yield the same results whatever the configuration I am using
- The set of possible configuration is high (below it is (5-Version) x 2 (with/without optimization) x 7 days x  Others parameters = a lot

Currently I am inheriting a bases class that contains all the tests but it is not really scalable. What approach can work ? Is there something like *TestCaseSource* but at the class level ?

Current code :

```
public sealed class NoOptimization_Version0_Weekday_Tests : FeatureTestsBase
{
    protected override void SpecificSetup()
    {
        this.version = 0;
        this.withOptimizatin = false;
        this.dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday;
    }
}
public sealed class NoOptimization_Version1_Weekday_Tests : FeatureTestsBase
{
    protected override void SpecificSetup()
    {
        this.version = 1;
        this.withOptimizatin = false;
        this.dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday;
    }
}
public sealed class NoOptimization_Version1_Weekend_Tests : FeatureTestsBase
{
    protected override void SpecificSetup()
    {
        this.version = 1;
        this.withOptimizatin = false;
        this.dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday;
    }
}

//...and many more specificSetups

[TestFixture]
public abstract class FeatureTestsBase
{
    protected int version;
    protected bool withOptimizatin;
    protected DayOfWeek dayOfWeek;

    public void SetUp()
    {
        SpecificSetup();
        //CommonSetup();
    }

    protected abstract void SpecificSetup();

    [Test]
    public void Test_00()
    {
        //...
    }

    //...

    [Test]
    public void Test_99()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain why TestCaseSource  will not work for you?

Comment: The main issue is that I will need to change ALL the test to include the testCase source + I need  specific a management for the tests that already uses [TestsCase].

Comment: Stuff you haven't said... Whether this is NUnit 2 or 3? What version exactly? Do you want to set up just one option per run, repeating multiple times, or have multiple options during the same run? Do you want this to be hard-coded or driven from the command-line? There are different ways to do it... depending.

Comment: And yes, there is something like `TestCaseSource` but at the class level. Not surprisingly, it's called `TestFixtureSource`. :-)

Comment: @Charlie , ok indeed actually `TestFixture` does allow parameters. Not perfect because I need to generate all the possible options as an attribute, but a quick script will do the job ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide parameters for your TestFixture.
I'm not sure what you want to do with the provided values and so on, but this is a way to do this.

```cs
[TestFixture(1, false, DayOfWeek.Monday)]
[TestFixture(1, false, DayOfWeek.Sunday)]
class TestFixtureTests
{
    private readonly int version;
    private readonly bool withOptimization;
    private readonly DayOfWeek dayOfWeek;

    public TestFixtureTests(int version, bool withOptimization, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
    {
        this.version = version;
        this.withOptimization = withOptimization;
        this.dayOfWeek = dayOfWeek;
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestSomething()
    {
        Assert.That(dayOfWeek, Is.EqualTo(DayOfWeek.Monday).Or.EqualTo(DayOfWeek.Sunday));
    }
}
```

Comment: It is what I've wrote. The 'issue' being the huge list of different testFixture that need to be generated (a quick script did the job but it is not really convenient nor flexible).